# C# Change Namespace Prefix on Root Node of SyndicationItem

Tags: c#, xml, syndication, syndication-item

Not even sure if I'm asking the right question, but here it goes. Basically because of a lack of support of the WCF DS client for "OData deep inserts" I'm having to manually build up an Atom request. I have the request nearly complete, the only thing that is missing (and it causing a problem on the request to the server) is add the namespace prefix to the "entry" node in the XML request.

I'm using a SyndicationItem to build the request up. I need to prefix the "entry" node with "atom:" for the server to accept the request...

Any help is much appreciated. Here is the request that is being generated now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <atom:id>uuid:8ed93950-9c16-4923-b6cc-ca5c7d020709;id=1</atom:id>
  <atom:title type="text"></atom:title>
  <atom:updated>2011-11-03T23:02:40Z</atom:updated>
  <atom:link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/SalesOrderItems" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="SALES_ORDER.SalesOrderHeader_SalesOrderItemsx" href="SalesOrderHeaders()/SalesOrderItems">
    <m:inline>
      <atom:feed>
        <atom:entry>
          <atom:content>
            <m:properties>
              <d:Item>10</d:Item>
              <d:Material>70000559</d:Material>
              <d:Plant>570B</d:Plant>
              <d:Quantity>10</d:Quantity>
            </m:properties>
          </atom:content>
        </atom:entry>
        <atom:entry>
          <atom:content>
            <m:properties>
              <d:Item>20</d:Item>
              <d:Material>70000559</d:Material>
              <d:Plant>570B</d:Plant>
              <d:Quantity>10</d:Quantity>
            </m:properties>
          </atom:content>
        </atom:entry>
      </atom:feed>
    </m:inline>
  </atom:link>
  <atom:content type="text/xml">
    <m:properties>
      <d:DocumentType>ZCSH</d:DocumentType>
      <d:CustomerId>0001008657</d:CustomerId>
      <d:SalesOrg>1100</d:SalesOrg>
      <d:DistChannel>10</d:DistChannel>
      <d:Division>40</d:Division>
    </m:properties>
  </atom:content>
</entry>
```

And here is the code I have right now to generate the request. This is just a proof of concept, so please ignore the crap. :)

```
XNamespace nsAtom = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
            XNamespace nsD = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices";
            XNamespace nsM = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata";

            SyndicationItem soHeader = new SyndicationItem();

            soHeader.AttributeExtensions.Add(new XmlQualifiedName("atom", XNamespace.Xmlns.ToString()), nsAtom.NamespaceName);
            soHeader.AttributeExtensions.Add(new XmlQualifiedName("d", XNamespace.Xmlns.ToString()), nsD.NamespaceName);
            soHeader.AttributeExtensions.Add(new XmlQualifiedName("m", XNamespace.Xmlns.ToString()), nsM.NamespaceName);


            soHeader.Content = SyndicationContent.CreateXmlContent(
                new XElement(nsM + "properties",
                    new XElement(nsD + "DocumentType", "ZCSH"),
                    new XElement(nsD + "CustomerId", "0001008657"),
                    new XElement(nsD + "SalesOrg", "1100"),
                    new XElement(nsD + "DistChannel", "10"),
                    new XElement(nsD + "Division", "40")
                    )
                );

            SyndicationLink link = SyndicationLink.CreateAlternateLink(new Uri("SalesOrderHeaders()/SalesOrderItems", UriKind.Relative), "application/atom+xml;type=feed");
            link.Title = "SALES_ORDER.SalesOrderHeader_SalesOrderItems";
            link.RelationshipType = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/SalesOrderItems";
            soHeader.Links.Add(link);

            XElement items = new XElement(nsM + "inline",
                                new XElement(nsAtom + "feed")
                                    );

            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                items.Element(nsAtom + "feed").Add(new XElement(nsAtom + "entry",
                            new XElement(nsAtom + "content",
                                new XElement(nsM + "properties",
                                    new XElement(nsD + "Item", ((i+1)*10).ToString()),
                                    new XElement(nsD + "Material", "70000559"),
                                    new XElement(nsD + "Plant", "570B"),
                                    new XElement(nsD + "Quantity", (Decimal)10.0)
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        );
            }

            link.ElementExtensions.Add(items);

            XmlWriter xml = XmlWriter.Create("C:\\test.xml");            
            soHeader.SaveAsAtom10(xml);
            xml.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entry element is in the ATOM namespace as it should be, it's just not using any prefix. If you remove the namespace declaration of atom prefix you're adding manually, all the ATOM elements will be in the ATOM namespace still, but without the atom prefix. Note that the entry elements declares the default namespace to be ATOM namespace.
Any XML compliant server should be able to read this payload. Removing the atom prefix will just make the payload smaller.

Comment: I think the problem is that the server isn't processing the payload correctly. I think it is requiring a prefix on all elements.  Is there a way I can force the prefix for this entry element?  Thanks